# Jade array as item for Django

Tags: django, django-templates, pug, pyjade

I'm using PyJade in Django and i have a problem with association of arrays with item.

In Django Template:

```
{% get_providers as socialaccount_providers %}
```

How can i make this using Jade?

Answer (score 0):

In pyjade you can do :

```
ul
for get_providers in socialaccount_providers
    li= get_providers
```

I do not know if you have your Django setup for using pyjade?
If not, you need to do so.